# Firefox no sound (v57.0.2) in Windows 10 rs_prerelease 17063

Tags: firefox, audio, windows-10-preview

Firefox 57.0.2 is unable to play sound after switching to this Windows release.
Also affects Nightly and Developers edition
eg youtube video plays on chrome/edge not on firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Logged and confirmed as a known issue by Microsoft.

Microsoft response
Windows has several audio volume APIs - IAudioEndpointVolume, IChannelAudioVolume, ISimpleAudioVolume, and IAudioEndpointVolume. These APIs can be used to change the volume and/or mute state of the stream, app, or audio device.

In build 17063 a change was made to these APIs to have them return S_FALSE (1) if the requested change was a no-op.

This broke apps (like Firefox) which request changes (that may be no-ops) and then explicitly check the return value against S_OK (0).

Answer (score 1):

It was determined to be [a Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1426719). The problem has been fixed in Nightly, and [should](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/7kzt7s/psa_if_you_use_firefox_dont_upgrade_to_17063_it/drleits/) make its way to 58 beta, 57 release and 52 ESR as soon as possible